# Windows Installer for Office solution by using Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

**UPD:** I found old article that I used a few years ago and followed me step-by-step with deploy using Windows Installer [Deploying a VSTO Solution Using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019). Problem solved

---

I wrote a custom add-ins menu for Office using Visual Studio Community 2019. Now I'm trying to deploy it. In this article [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019)  they used VS2013 and InstallShield Limited Edition, which doesn't work with VS Community 2019. I installed Advanced Installer but in the Help section "Create a package to deploy an Office Add-In developed in Visual Studio" says "*The following article uses options that are available **starting with the Professional edition** and project type.*" what means I need to upgrade free version to commercial.

Could you please recommend any other Windows Installer for Office solution for Visual Studio **Community** 2019? Or any step-by-step article how to deploy solution by using Setup Project in VS Community 2019?

I remember I tried to do some deploy in old version of VS a few years ago, but nowadays it seems more complicated. I just want to try and see if my add-ins work in another computer and then I'll think about commercial versions of VS or Installers

Thanks,
Elena

Answer (score 1):

You can build the package using the free version of Advanced Installer too, but you will have to [create all the registry entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019#ConfigureRegistry) (those related to your addin) manually and also the same for adding the files in the package, as documented in the MS article.

The wizard that you mention above does this automatically by reading the necessary info to make the configs from your Visual Studio solution.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: I tried Advanced Installer, but it wasn't successful, because of my luck of knowledge how to properly Registry application. But thanks anyway

Comment: Well, here's a trick (but don't tell anyone I shared it :) ) - create a project with the trial version of Advanced Installer - using the dedicated wizard for office addins. Then see what this project contains in Files and Folders and Registry pages and replicate it manually into a new "Simple" (free edition) project.